# The VMargument values not properly read by log4j2.properties

Tags: spring, tomcat, log4j2

Spring web application with log4j2 implemented in tomcat 8 running in windows and linux servers.
In windows server
CATALINA_OPTS specified in setenv.bat file

`set "CATALINA_OPTS=-DLOG_FOLDER=D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\customlog"`

log4j2.properties file is inside WEB-INF\classes\config\

```
appender.rolling.fileName=${sys:LOG_FOLDER}\logger.log
appender.rolling.filePattern=${sys:LOG_FOLDER}\logging-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz
```

In linux server
CATALINA_OPTS specified in setenv.sh file

`set "CATALINA_OPTS=-DLOG_FOLDER=/opt/tomcat01/customlog"`

log4j2.properties file is inside WEB-INF\classes\config\

```
appender.rolling.fileName=${env:LOG_FOLDER}/logger.log
appender.rolling.filePattern=${env:LOG_FOLDER}/logging-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz
```

log folder is always created like '${env:LOG_FOLDER}' or '${sys:LOG_FOLDER}'

Answer (score 1):

You should use `${sys:LOG_FOLDER}` in both cases:

- `${sys:property_name}` retrieves the Java system property of that name,
- `${env:variable_name}` retrieves the OS environment variable of that name.

See [Log4j 2 Lookups](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) for more details.

There are also other problems in your configuration:

- if you start Tomcat on Windows as a service, `setenv.bat` is not used. You should add `-DLOG_FOLDER=D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\customlog` to the Java tab of the Tomcat Monitor application (`bin\tomcat<version>w.exe`).
- on Linux you are using the wrong syntax to modify an environment variable (Microsoft's syntax), use:

```sh
export CATALINA_OPTS="-DLOG_FOLDER=/opt/tomcat01/customlog"
```

instead.

**Remark:** If you want to use environment variables instead of system properties, you can use:

```sh
export LOG_FOLDER="/opt/tomcat01/customlog"
```

on Linux, while on Windows you need to run:

```cmd
tomcat10.exe //US ++Environment="LOG_FOLDER=D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\customlog"
```

See [Procrun documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html#Command_line_parameters) for more details.